# How to move sign separate trailing to normal decimal field in COBOL

Tags: edit, numeric, cobol

I have a field like
03 ws-var1  Pic s9(11)v9(2) sign trailing separate.

In the op file the value gets displayed as 00000002999200+

But I want it to be displayed as 29992.00. What definition has to be made in COBOL to so tht  I get this desired result.

Comment: Use the definition PIC -Z(10)9.99  Move the WS-VAR1 to a display field, then output.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc That comment is totally the correct answer. While the question may be extended to increase its usefulness, do you mind to move it to an answer with a minimal note about edited fields in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

| PICTURE | Result | Length | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| +9(11).9(2) | +00000029992.00 | 15 | The sign `+` or `-` will be shown |
| -9(11).9(2) | 00000029992.00 | 15 | The `-` will show only if the value is negative |
| +(11)9.9(2) | +29992.00 | 15 | The sign `+` or `-` will be shown |
| -(11)9.9(2) | 29992.00 | 15 | The `-` will show only if the value is negative |
| Z(10)9.9(2) | 29992.00 | 14 | The sign is removed. |

In each case spaces will be present before each result if the number of characters shown is less the the length of the field.